# 'undefined' in jquery each loop in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have try to create a table dynamically by using jQuery like below

```
 $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                rows = rows + '<tr>' + '<td style="width:20px" style="text-align: center;"><input type="radio" userid=' + item.UserId + ' checked="checked" name="SummaryTemplateRadio" id="savedSummaryTemplate' + item.SummaryTemplateSavedId + '"></td>' +
                    '<td class="tcol1" id="summaryTemplateName' + item.SummaryTemplateSavedId + '" style="text-align: left;">' + item.TemplateName + '</td>' +
                    '<td class="tcol2"  style="text-align: left;">' + item.CreationDate + '</td>' +
                    '<td class="tcol3" id="summaryTemplateDesc' + item.SummaryTemplateSavedId + '" style="text-align: left;">' + item.TemplateDescription + '</td>' +
                    '<td class="tcol4" style="text-align: left;">' + item.UserId + '</td>' +
                    '<td class="tcol5" style="text-align: left;">' + item.NoOfMeasures + '</td>' +

                    '</tr>';
            });
            $('.loadTemplatepopup .allTemplateTable tbody').html(rows);
```

the problem is when it runs in IE9, 'undefined' is print in table like below
[image]

undefined is because, in jquery each loop index variable is comes as undefined? IE10 and others browsers working fine. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess here: it's not `index` that is the problem but `rows`.

Your code is probably:

```
var rows;
$.each(/**/)
```

Change it to:

```
var rows = "";
$.each(/**/)
```

Or something like:

```
rows = (rows || "") + '<tr>..etc..</tr>';
```

Comment: I had already initialized rows before the loop.. Index is undefined not rows.it's already I pointed out in the question.

Comment: I highly doubt that it is undefined because it comes from `.each()`. Even if it is undefined you shouldn't see it in the output because you don't add `index` to the string anywhere.

Comment: when I remove index from the each loop..I can't access the property corresponding to item

Comment: `index` is not the problem here, it's fine as it is. Check `rows`.

Comment: it's the pblm..I try to debug it and index is come as undefined

Comment: How are you debugging it?

Comment: by using ie debugger.

Comment: I don't know. I've given up on trying to explain why IE does what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put your rows in

```
if (data.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
}
```

It will solve your problem cross browsers. Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

```
The  issue is a very tricky one , Here it goes 

when you use "**$(array).each**" jquery clause in **IE** along with the iterator object array, it also returns the **prototype** of the array as an element ....which when tries to run the function nested in it,,,,,it breaks!

The solution would be to add a null check for the individual items in the iterator function. 

 $(myObjectArray).each(function (key, value) {
        if(typeof value !="undefined")
        someOtherCode(value.webName, value.webPath, value.libraryName);
    });
```